# Thread.sleep is blocking other thread also, working on other method, along with itself callled inside synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
class Common
{

public synchronized void synchronizedMethod1() 
    {
        System.out.println("synchronized Method1 called");
        try
        {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("synchronized Method1 done");
    }

public synchronized void synchronizedMethod2() 
{
    System.out.println("synchronized Method2 called");
    try
    {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("synchronized Method2 done");
}
}
```

In the above class I have two synchronized methods which I am calling from run method of another class. Other class code is given below:

```
public class ThreadClass implements Runnable
{
    private int id = 0;
    private Common common;

public ThreadClass(int no, Common object)
{
    common = object;
    id = no;
}

public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Running Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try 
    {
        if (id == 11) 
        {
            common.synchronizedMethod1();
        } 
        else
        {
            common.synchronizedMethod2();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Common c = new Common();
    ThreadClass tc = new ThreadClass(11, c);
    ThreadClass tc1 = new ThreadClass(20, c);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(tc, "Thread 1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(tc1, "Thread 2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

From main method I am starting two different threads. In run method I have given a condition to send both different threads to different synchronized methods. Output produced by the code is:

```
Running Thread Thread 2
Running Thread Thread 1
synchronized Method2 called
synchronized Method2 done
synchronized Method1 called
synchronized Method1 done
```

**MY QUESTION FOR THE OUTPUT IS:**
When thread 2 goes to synchronized Method2 it prints 3rd line of output and goes to sleep for 1 second. Now since thread 1 is not blocked by anything so it should execute and print 5th line of the output just after 3rd line of output and should go to sleep then but this is not happening instead when thread 2 goes to sleep it make's thread 1 also sleep then first thread 2 complete's its execution after which thread 1 completes its execution.

Such a behavior is not happening if I remove synchronized keyword from methods.
Can you please explain me the reason behind different way of processing the code with and without synchronized keywords.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *since thread 1 is not blocked by anything*: it **is** blocked, since it needs to enter the synchronized method, but can't since thread 2 already holds the lock (and is sleeping while holding it). That's the whole principle of synchronized methods.

Comment: @Nizet: I know about the concept of synchronized keyword but since my program is not following it that's why I am getting confused about the keyword working. Also in my program both threads are acting on different synchronized methods so if thread 2 has blocked method 1 and went to sleep then it should not hinder the working of thread 1 which is acting on other synchronized method. And this is my query in my post that why thread 2 is blocking thread 1 to enter other synchronized method which has not been blocked by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Such a behavior is not happening if I remove synchronized keyword from methods. Can you please explain me the reason behind different way of processing the code with and without synchronized keywords.

This is actually the entire purpose of the `synchronized` keyword. When you have several synchronized instance methods of the same class, only one may be executing at a time. You have written this:

```
class Common {
    public synchronized void synchronizedMethod1(){}
    public synchronized void synchronizedMethod2(){}
}
```

Because both methods are synchronized, only one may be executed at once. One of them can't start the other one is done.

How does this work? In short, you have a `Common` object and call a synchronized instance method of it. When you call `synchronzedMethod1`, that method will "lock" the `Common` object (called "acquiring the lock"). While that method has that lock on that `Common` object, if you try to call any other synchronized method on that same object, it will try to lock it and it will find that it's already locked. So any other attempt to lock the object will hang until they can do so. Once `synchronizedMethod1` finishes, it will unlock the `Common` object (called "releasing the lock") and anybody can then try to lock it, such as `synchronzedMethod2`.

So in short, `synchronized` specifically makes it so you can't have two synchronized methods of the same class happening at once. This is useful because some problematic behavior can come from not doing this. As an example, `ArrayList` does not do this, so if one thread tries to add an object to an `ArrayList` while another tries to iterate over it, it might throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` and make everyone sad.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply. By your answer and after searching through net about more detailed concept of synchronized method I understood the behavior of my code.

Comment: @AbuzarSiddiqui if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer lately. Thanks again for your nice reply.

Answer (score 0):

A sleeping thread does not release its locks, but you can replace your `sleep(...)` calls with `wait(...)`. Keep in mind, though, that only the lock of the object having `wait(...)` called on it will be released, so you'd have to devise a different solution if you expected multiple locks to be released while waiting.

Comment: its better you also mention sleep() is a static method which means only affects caller thread but wait is an instance method that has to be accessed through an instance

Answer (score -1):

First of all `synchronized` keyword is used to define mutual exclusion. Here mutual exclusion achieved by **Monitor** concept. One more thing is `sleep` does not release monitor. It just pause the execution of current thread for some time. Other threads which requires the monitor have to wait until the thread which acquired monitor release it.

There is two ways to use `synchronized`...

First one is using synchronized blocks.

```
synchronized(obj){...}
```

Here if any thread want to enter into synchronized block it have to get monitor of obj.

Second one is to using synchronized method.

```
synchronized void meth(){...}
```

Main difference between synchronised method & block is **synchronised method use monitor of object it self & synchronised block can have monitor of any object**.

Synchronized method can be defined using synchronized block as follows...

```
void meth(){
    synchronized (this){
        //method body
    }
}
```

Now you can use the synchronised block to prevent the problem of blocking another method. Here you have to define synchronised block on different objects so both methods can execute concurrently but multiple threads can not execute same method concurrently.

Comment: '*Is* used'. 'Achieved'. 'Postpone'. 'There *are* two ways'. 'It *has* to get ... '.

Answer (score -1):

synchronising a method doesnt mean just the method itself synchronised

```
synchronized void x(){}
```

equals to:

```
 void x(){ 
  synchronised(this){}
 }
```

Since both thread access same `Common` instance first thread will get the ownership of the Common object lock doesnt matter which synchronised method called and it will just release this lock after this method body completed its job. 
 If you would send two Common instance there would not be a problem since they are not static. Also you might be interested in [ReentrantLock](http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2013/03/reentrantlock-example-in-java-synchronized-difference-vs-lock.html)